# Как отключить проверку сертификата в модуле requests?

Tags: python, requests

Как на уровне самого модуля `requests`, в его файлах отключить проверку сертификатов?
Чтобы когда какое либо приложение использующее данный модуль отправляла `get` запрос не проверялся сертификат...
В каком файле этого модуля можно этого сделать?

Comment: Извиняюсь за ошибки, торопился.. я использую python 3.8.6

Comment: requests.get(url, verify=False)

Comment: Сэр, я имел  в виду как отключить эту проверку на уровне самой библиотеки, чтобы этот параметр оставался отключенным всегда, понимаете ? чтобы по умолчанию было verify =False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> нужно отключить эту проверку на уровне самого модуля, а не в своем
> приложении, чтобы не приходилось постоянно указывать в коде
> verify=False

В вашем виртуальном окружении по адресу (python3.6 может быть другим):

```
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py
```

можно найти `def request()`:

```
def request(self, method, url,
            params=None, data=None, headers=None, cookies=None, files=None,
            auth=None, timeout=None, allow_redirects=True, proxies=None,
            hooks=None, stream=None, verify=None, cert=None, json=None):
```

измените `verify=None` на `verify=False`... хотя затея - так себе...

Comment: согласен с @Jack_oS, затея так себе. Все таки переопределение помогает не притрагиваться к внутренностям пакетов.

Answer (score 2):

> Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set
> verify to False:

```
requests.get('https://kennethreitz.org', verify=False) <Response [200]>
```

> Note that when verify is set to False, requests will accept any
> TLS certificate presented by the server, and will ignore hostname
> mismatches and/or expired certificates, which will make your
> application vulnerable to man-in-the-middle (MitM) attacks. Setting
> verify to False may be useful during local development or testing.

Укажи параметр `verify=False` чтоб пропустить проверкеу сертификата, но лучше положи сертификат вместе со своим приложением и в параметре verify укажи путь к нему.

Этот же параметр присутствует в Session объекте. Создай сессию без проверки и используй её вместо модуля.

```
session = requests.Session(verify=False)

session.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
r = session.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies')
```

Comment: Сэр, мне нужно отключить эту проверку на уровне самого модуля, а не в своем приложении. Чтобы не приходилось постоянно указывать в коде verify=False.Спасибо.

Comment: @MovsarCoder дополнил ответ

Comment: Понимаете, я хочу манипулировать одним приложением написанным на python, как раз таки он используют проверку сертификата, я хочу отключить эту проверку изменив сам модуль requests.Где конкретно в sessions.py отключить проверку ?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю свой вариант переопределения `get` запроса.

```
import requests.api

def custom_get(url, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault("verify", False)
    return requests.api.request("get", url, **kwargs)

request.api.get = custom_get
```

Использовать `Sessions` я бы стал при необходимости переопределения всех запросов, но тоже реально